# jQuery check cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to check if the user has a cookie, and if not- run the jQuery code.

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work... I have a syntax mistake.

```
<code>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(
if($.cookie('car') == undefined){
function() {    

        var id = '#dialog';

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(2000);     

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

}});
</script>
</code>
```

Comment: Are you in fact including the jQuery cookie plugin which would allow you to use `$.cookie()`?

Comment: You will need: http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

Answer (score 1):

$.cookie() requires jQuery Cookie plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie